# How to set tags to AWS IAM Policies using Power Shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-iam

The documentation of New-IAMPolicy cmdlet talks about the -Tag parameter:

> -Tag <Tag[]>
> A list of tags that you want to attach to the new IAM customer managed policy. Each tag consists of a key name and an associated value. For more information about tagging, see Tagging IAM resources in the IAM User Guide.If any one of the tags is invalid or if you exceed the allowed maximum number of tags, then the entire request fails and the resource is not created.

But there is an exception

```
 | A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tag'.
```

Then, looking for a specific cmdlet to do it, filtering per IAM and Tag I get these:

```
Cmdlet          Add-IAMAAResourceTag                               4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Add-IAMRoleTag                                     4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Add-IAMUserTag                                     4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Get-IAMAAResourceTag                               4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Get-IAMRoleTagList                                 4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Get-IAMUserTagList                                 4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Remove-IAMAAResourceTag                            4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Remove-IAMRoleTag                                  4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Cmdlet          Remove-IAMUserTag                                  4.1.0.0    AWSPowerShell.NetCore
```

But nothing related to IAM Policy.

What is the way to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This one should work

```
$PolicyTag = New-Object Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.Tag
$PolicyTag.Key = "CreatedBy"
$PolicyTag.Value = "PowerShell"

New-IAMPolicy -Policy "NameofPolicy" -PolicyDocument "PolicyDocument.json" -Tag $PolicyTag
```